# C++ overloaded new[] query : What size does it take as parameter?

Tags: c++, overloading, new-operator

I have overloadded operator new[] like this

```
void * human::operator new[] (unsigned long int count){
      cout << " calling new for array with size  = " << count <<  endl  ;
      void * temp = malloc(count) ;  
      return temp ; 
}
```

and now calling

```
human * h = new human[14] ;
```

say `sizeof(human) = 16` , but count it prints is 232 which is 14*16 + sizeof( int * ) = 224+8 .

Why is this extra space being allocated ? And where does it fall in memory ?
Because when I print `*h` OR `h[0]` I get same results , so its not in beginning of memory chunk. Is it correct at all OR I am missing some thing here ?

Comment: Good question. Yet the nitpicker inside me needs to point out that you don't check for malloc() returning a null pointer.

Comment: @sharptooth  : u r right but that was intentional coz I wanted to focus on real question and not add too many ifs :) Ideally one needs to check for temp !=0 else throw some exception (bad_alloc kinda )

Comment: Extra bytes are for storing the number of bytes allocated. But where it stores is implementation dependent.

Comment: This is clearly an abuse of operator overloading. `foo[i]` should mean "look up element number i in foo", not "allocate i bytes of memory".

Comment: @fredOverflow : why that's an abuse ? how else would you create array of objects on heap ?

Comment: @FredOverflow : you probably misread the code, it is `operator new[]`, not `operator[]`

Comment: @Yos: Indeed that's what happened :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The extra space allocated is used to store the size of the array for internal usage (in practice so that `delete[]` knows how much to delete).

It *is* stored at the beginning of the memory range, immediately *before* `&h`. To see this, just look at the value of `temp` inside your `operator new[]`. The value will differ from that in `&h`.

Answer (score 3):

It is to store the number of objects allocated so that when you invoke `delete[]` proper number of objects are deleted. See this [FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/freestore-mgmt.html#faq-16.14) for more details.