# c++ overloading new[], get number of requested objects

Tags: c++, overloading

I want to overload the operator new[] to get the number of how many objects are to be created.
the best possible solution is to overload new[] in a way that the when creating an object using new[] would not necessitate the caller to write any extra code. 
i.e using simply:

```
Myclass objectsArray = new Myclass[5];
```

example overload:

```
class Myclass
{
 ...
public:
void* operator new[](size_t size)
{
   int numberOfObjects = figure out how to get number of objects to be created by this call to new[]
   std::cout << "requesting: " << numberOfObjects << " objects" << std::endl;
   void * temp = malloc(size) ;  
   return temp ; 
}
...
}
```

the following example program:

```
Myclass objectsArray = new Myclass[4];
```

would output:

```
requesting: 4 objects
```

edit:
I want to do this just in MyClass not globaly

edit:
I'm on ‎Lubuntu 12.0 with GCC version 4.8.1

edit: Purpose of the question:

I'm using a custom memory pool allocator that can't allocate arrays out of the box. so I need to know how many objects are requested and create them one by one using a loop with the pool allocator.

Comment: idk about this, exTrace

Comment: Perhaps you want to overload operator new for individual classes rather than globally?  What is your end goal here?

Comment: int numberOfObject = size / sizeof(*this) if the new[] is defined in  Myclass

Comment: @JohnZwinck I want to overload new[] just in MyClass not globaly.

Comment: For overloading in a specific class take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406199/overloading-operator-new-for-a-class?rq=1)

Comment: @Lucian `*this` is unavailable for static member functions, and size / sizeof(MyClass) is also wrong cause size always has extra memory size for storing information about the array. see here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012524/c-overloaded-new-query-what-size-does-it-take-as-parameter)

Comment: This looks like an x-y problem. What do you want to use that information for?

Comment: @molbdnilo I'm using a custom memory pool allocator that can't allocate arrays out of the box. so I need to know how many objects are requested and create them one by one using a loop with the pool allocator.

Comment: you can always overload e version of new with your object count, new( size_t size, size_t n)

Comment: @privatedatapublicchannel2 but then I would have to declare my objects as: MyClass objectsArray = new(4) Myclass[4]; what would happen is old client code that was using "new MyClass[4]" will call the new( size_t size) operator which needs the number of requested objects to create with the custom memory pool allocator.

Comment: @exTrace101 OK. If you put that information in the question you're more likely to get useful answers, as someone might have solved the ultimate problem before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a class-specific `operator new`. This works for me, but beware of alignment, derived classes sizes, and allocation overhead issues in the `count/sizeof(MyClass)` expression:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <new>

struct MyClass {
    int dummy[8];
    void *operator new[](std::size_t count) {
        std::cout << "allocating " << count << " bytes, " << ((count-sizeof(void*))/sizeof(MyClass)) << " items\n";
        return ::operator new[](count);
    }
};

int main() {
  auto x = std::make_unique<MyClass[]>(10);
}
```

(prints: `allocating 10 items`) I think one can determine the exact overhead for your compiler/stdlib combination empirically by doing something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <new>

struct MyClass {
  char c;
  char d;
    virtual ~MyClass() {} // needed for introducing overhead
    void *operator new[](std::size_t count) {
        void *p = ::operator new[](count);
        std::cout << "allocating " << count << " bytes\n";
        return p;
    }
};

int main() {
  for( auto count : { 1, 5, 10, 20 } ) {
    std::cout << "allocating " << sizeof(MyClass) << " * " << count << " items\n";
    auto x = new MyClass[count];
    delete[] x;
  }
}
```

This will print, in my machine (and on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd9ae26e5c0e99e4)):

allocating 16 * 1 items
allocating 24 bytes, 1 items
allocating 16 * 5 items
allocating 88 bytes, 5 items
allocating 16 * 10 items
allocating 168 bytes, 10 items
allocating 16 * 20 items
allocating 328 bytes, 20 items

So, our `count/sizeof(MyClass)` (here) should be something like

```
(count-sizeof(void*))/sizeof(MyClass)
```

But YMMV, etc.

**LAST EDIT** (I hope)

I had success on 64-bits linux (clang-3.4, clang-3.5 & gcc-4.8, libstdc++ & libc++) with the following `how_many_elements` function:

```
template<class T>
    std::size_t how_many_elements(std::size_t bytes) {
  return (bytes -
    ((!std::is_trivially_destructible<T>::value)*sizeof(void*))
    ) / sizeof(T);
}
```

So your `operator new` becomes something like:

```
void *operator new[](std::size_t count) {
    std::cout << "allocating " << count << " bytes, " << how_many_elements<MyClass>(count) << " items\n";
    return ::operator new[](count);
}
```

But I have not tested it in 32-bits environments and the YMMV still applies. And remember to replicate the `operator new` for **every** derived class of `MyClass`, obviously replacing `MyClass` for `MyDerivedClass` or whatever...

Comment: Only works if the new expression overhead is < `sizeof(MyClass)`. Also, does not work for derived classes > `sizeof(MyClass)`.

Comment: @Deduplicator hence my comment "beware of alignment issues" -- edited for clarity :D

Comment: That's only just related, because in most implementations it is a part of the calculations, if some conditions hold. Perhaps mention the platform ABI and compiler manual as good information sources for the exact calculations.

Comment: does not work for me, I try Myclass = new Myclass[4] and as result I get: "allocating 6 items", [the reason is here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012524/c-overloaded-new-query-what-size-does-it-take-as-parameter)

Comment: @exTrace101: For the exact formula, look at the right C++ platform ABI and/or compiler documentation. You really have to provide the exact applicable versions (aka it is implementation-defined). My educated guesses are, depending on your type and ABI: 0, max(sizeof(size_t), sizeof(MyClass)), max(sizeof(size_t), _Alignof(MyClass))

Comment: @exTrace101 that's the "`new` expression overhead" we've been talking about... what is the `sizeof` of your `MyClass`?

Comment: I am editing the answer again, with more clarifications (I hope) :D

Comment: @exTrace101 checking `libc++`'s and `libstdc++`'s sources, I can assure you there is no clear/clean/semiportable programatic way to do that. I suggest you use, for now, something like `how_many_elements` (see my latest edit above)

Comment: [Coliru link for the `how_many_elements` test](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0a2c9cde1895403b)